# Unable to use VS2015 Project installers with 64-bit project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, windows-installer

I was wondering if anyone was able to successfully create Installer Project for a 64-bit WinForms application on VS2015.

When I try to compile the installer project for simple 64-bit WinForms project that only displays a message box, I get the following:

> ERROR: File 'WindowsFormsApplication2.exe' of project output 'Primary
>   output from WindowsFormsApplication2 (Debug x64)' targeting 'AMD64' is
>   not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

And when opening the installer project properties I don't find any option for changing the installer project to x64.[image]

**Edit:**
I already tried the project properties:
[image]

However while the link provided in Cody Gray's comment is for VS2010, it suggests that "Creating 64-bit MSI packages is not available in Visual Studio Express Edition.
"
And I'm using VS2015 community which is free. Could that be the problem?

Comment: The knob is in the Properties window (not the Configuration Manager). See instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd7a85k9(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @Cody Gray please see the update to the question.

Comment: No, I doubt that's the problem. You are still looking in the wrong place. It is not the "Property Pages", but the Properties window. It is a floating tool window, possibly docked in your IDE. Click on the setup project in the Solution Explorer, then go to the Properties window. Change the `TargetPlatform` property.

Comment: thanks that worked :)